# Error created when validation error occurs on different tabs

Tags: asp.net

I am using an ajax tab control.  I am using a combination of required field validators and custom validators.  I am using a validation summary at the end of the page.  My problem is when there is a validation error on different tabs I get an IE error because it cannot set focus on all of the fields at once because they are on different tabs.  I know if I set focus on error to false the error does not occur.  Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Is that includes validation on server-side ?

Comment: Try to turn off LoadOnDemand option of your tab control if it has.

Comment: You could validate each tab when the user leaves it

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I tried turing off the LoanOnDemand and it had no affect.  The users may not visit each tab so I cannot validate when they leave.  The records are initally loaded by a batch job so the users then look at each record.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ValidationGroup of groups.. for more info [click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)

Comment: This did not work either.  There is only 1 function that is used to update all of the tabs.  So I have to validate both groups I created.  Thank you for the help.